# Show span title on click like on mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I show a span title on click on the span element? In general, the span title is shown on mouseover. So I want the same when the span is clicked. How can this be done?

```
<span title="abc">def</span>
```

Comment: You can't use the title attribute as browsers determine how they are rendered and you have no control.  You'd have to write some JavaScript to display a floating element, or similar, when the element is clicked.  If you google javascript tooltip there should be examples you can modify.

Comment: yes of course I can program that myself. I wanted to ask for a built-in feature. And no, clicking it does not show the title in Chrome

Comment: I'm curious as to the use case for this. It may be that a `span` is the wrong element here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can actually do this with a pseudo element.

It's not clear whether the 'click' is intended to mean mouse hold down (:active) or a formal 'click' process.

For the former, you can do this.

```css
span {
    position: relative;
}
span:active:after {
    content:attr(title);
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    top:5px;
    right:10%;
    background: #bada55;
}
```

```html
<span title="abc">def</span>
```

For the latter then adding a class that displays the pseudo element would be the obvious solution.

See this [**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9mmmwum4/2/)

Comment: uhm, how can I set the title content variable?

Comment: A full 'click' requires javascript so you could do this - http://jsfiddle.net/9mmmwum4/1/

Comment: yes your fiddle would be the best, but I do not want to write js for it, so I am going with the css content solution. Thank you

Comment: could you add content:attr(title); to your solution code?