# HTML Title Attribute - Decrease Delay and Also Display on Click

Tags: html, css, tooltip

How can I decrease the delay that occurs before advisory information is displayed via the html [title](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title) attribute, without scripting?:

```html
<p>
  Hover over the icon at the end of this sentence
  and notice the delay that occurs before the 
  advisory information is displayed.
  <span title="Any way to make this instant?">ⓘ</span>
 </p>
```

This would be a nice feature of HTML, if you could:

1. Adjust the delay.
2. Also display upon `click` (instead of just on `hover`).

I know how to achieve this with Javascript, so I'm only interested in HTML and CSS solutions.

Comment: There's no way we can control that, perhaps try this https://get.foundation/sites/docs-v5/components/tooltips.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show span title on click like on mouseover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27171102/show-span-title-on-click-like-on-mouseover)

Comment: As said you cant control that. It is a browser feature

Comment: @tacoshy : That's pretty cool, but slightly different than what I'm asking. For example, if text occurs after the example you provided, it gets shifted instead of displaying over the top like the title attribute does.

Comment: it's not possible to edit the title attribute but it's possible to have something similar using css

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To reduce the delay and show title instantly, you can do this with CSS `::after` selector.

**HTML:** (Change `title` attribute to `data-title`)

```
<p>
  Hover over the icon at the end of this sentence
  and notice the delay that occurs before the 
  advisory information is displayed.
    <span data-title="Anyway to make this instant?">ⓘ</span> 
</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
span 
{
    position: relative;
}

span:hover::after 
{
    content: attr(data-title);
    padding: 5px;
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    background: #dc143c;
    color: white;
}
```

**Demo:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        span 
        {
            position: relative;
        }

        span:hover::after 
        {
            content: attr(data-title);
            padding: 5px;
            width: 250px;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            position: absolute;
            top: 5px;
            left: 5px;
            background: #dc143c;
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        Hover over the icon at the end of this sentence
        and notice the delay that occurs before the 
        advisory information is displayed.
        <span data-title="Anyway to make this instant?">ⓘ</span> 
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

it can be achieved using label with hidden checkbox and using animation to control the delay, that'd trigger showing it on both click and hover, when clicked you need to click it again to hide it.

```css
input {
  display: none;
}

.tooltip-contents {
  opacity: 0;
  user-select: none;
}

input:not(:checked) + label:hover .tooltip-contents,
input:checked + label .tooltip-contents {
  opacity: 1;
  user-select: initial;
}

label:hover .tooltip-contents {
   animation-name: show;
   animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes show {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  99% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="tooltip-1">
<label for="tooltip-1">
  click or hover here for tooltip
  <p class="tooltip-contents">add your title text here</p>
</label>
```

Comment: The delay, though, is about the same.

Comment: changing animation-duration changes the delay to any value

Comment: Ah, that's true.

Comment: it's also possible to make the click instant and have the delay on hover only by having a separate set of properties for each

Comment: updated it to have instant click reaction and hover delay